# Get custom attribute before to authenticate user

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have multiple B2C users with blank password and extension_isNewsletter custom user attribute to true. Other B2C users were registered with their mails and password (not blank). In the login page, I would like to check if extension_isNewsletter claim exist just before to authenticate the user. If it exists, a REST API call will be done and no authentication process will be executed. Would it be possible, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I modified the SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email TechnicalProfile (TP):

```html
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
          <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" DefaultValue="" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isNewsletter"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserIsNewsletter" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

And the validationTechnicalProfile (AAD-UserIsNewsletter) would be:

```html
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserIsNewsletter">
          <Metadata>
              <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
              <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
              <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isNewsletter" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```